# Creating a "Switch" statement for Adobe Acrobat form fields

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I am having trouble createing the javascript switch statement for my PDF form.

I would like to have the "address, city, st, and zip" information populated for the fields based on a selected "provider". (each provider has their own respective Address/ City/ St/ Zip, etc etc).

Answer (score 1):

A switch takes the following format:

```
var match = 'match3';
switch(match){
  case 'match1':
    //
    break;
  case 'match2':
    // do stuff here
    break;
  case 'match3':
    console.log('test complete');
    break;
  default:
    // do this if all else fails
    break;
}
```

If your switch is inside a function you can change `break;` to `return;`. Obviously, `'match1'` and the like would be what you are looking to match.